# Losing bar when changing y-axis direction in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm playing around with d3.js and I ran into something weird.

When I change

```
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Distance})])
        .range([0, h])
```

to

```
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Distance})])
        .range([h, 0]) # CHANGED LINE
```

to get the axis to count in the right direction, one bar goes missing and the height of the remaining bars no longer corresponds with the value on the axis.

See here for a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/commesan/mu8v3j9o/)

I've checked the documentation and I can't find what I'm missing here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bar doesn't go missing. It just has the height of 0 (i.e. you can't see it) because you map the max value 118377 from your domain `[0, 118377]` to 0 from range (`[h, 0]`).

You can check it by right-clicking on the graph and clicking "inspect element" button. You will see three `rect` elements and the last of them will have `height="0"`.

I'm assuming you want the y axis to start from 0 at intersection with x axis. Take a look at this **[fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azubuk88/)** where I changed the attribute computation into the following:

```
...
 .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.Distance); })
 .attr("height", function(d) { return h - yScale(d.Distance); })
```

Comment: I see where I went wring there @Oleg, but when i change the domain to [118377, 0] the values of my y-axis flip back so it counts from top to bottom again instead of from bottom to top.

Comment: @commesan I've edited the answer by adding a link to a fork of your fiddle. Basically, if you invert the range, you need to adjust the attribute computation accordingly.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks @Oleg I would have lost hours before I found that.